# Images won't show up after uploading them

Tags: html, upload, jpeg

I have created an website and tested it local with Xammp and all images are loaded correct.
Now I have moved all files to my host and most of the images are shown. What might be wrong?
If I enter the path manually the image also not shown but it's placed on the server.

validator.w3.or Does not give any related errors.

[image]

[image]

Link that I use: `<img align="right" hspace="10" src="images/photo/watersnijden.jpg" />`

Css for the background:

```
background: url(../images/photo/achtergrond.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Some code will be helpfull...

Comment: How are you confirming that all the images you have 'uploaded' has is present on the server? Do you have a online file manager / ftp account using which you can check and make sure the images have uploaded properly?

Comment: 1. Did all the images copied over to the server? 2. Is the file damaged? 3. Any image type blocked in your server configuration?

Comment: @Ajuankysmith I wil add some code.

Comment: @CodeCanvas I have checked with FilleZilla.

Comment: @Robby Shaw Image types are not blocked. Some other jpg files are shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some images had been uploaded as JGP instead jpg. I still don't understand why the host gives me this problems and I have on my local system no problems.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using relative urls for inline images.

```
src="images/photo/watersnijden.jpg"
```

When you do that, your browser looks for the image at an addreess which is the current address in the browser, + the image path.

Add a forward slash to all these src values, and you might have more luck, assuming that the images directory is a direct child of the root web directory (httpdocs or similar)